# Как через консоль обратиться к браузеру по умолчанию. С

Tags: c, cmd, браузер

Консольную команду планирую передать функции `system()` из `stdlib.h`

Comment: Почему именно `system`? На винде браузер открывается через `ShellExecute`, вроде.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сделал через ShellExecute, заработало. Спасибо